# Power Bi 'column specified multiple times' error when using SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

When I run the below code in SQL Server, I get no errors. However, when I run it through Power Bi's SQL Server query, I get an error stating:

> Microsoft SQL: The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'SourceQuery'

```
select * 
from [DF1] a 
left join [DF_H] b on a.ID = b.ID 
where b.Status is not null 
  and year(b.Status_Date) != '1900' 
  and a.Category = 2
Union 
select * 
from [DF1] a 
left join [DF_D] b on a.ID = b.ID
where b.Claim_Status is not null 
  and year(b.Status_Date) != '1900' 
  and a.Category = 2
```

Any help would be appreciated and I can give any additional information that may be required

Comment: Presumably `DF1` and `DF_H` both have a column named `ID`.  PowerBI doesn' t know which one you want to use.  Don't use `SELECT *`, only include the columns you need in your `SELECT` statements.  SSMS is more forgiving of this (since SQL Server allows it) which is why it works when you run it in SSMS.

Comment: As both objects aliased as `a` and `b`  (which are poor aliases for objects called `DF1` and `DF_H` as neither have an `a` or `b` in their name)  have a column called `id`, you have *at least* 2 columns with the name `id` too.

Comment: You get no errors because SQL Server doesn't care if your (final) result set has multiple columns with the same name (`DF1.ID`, `DF_H.ID`, `DF_D.ID`..). Power BI does, however.

Comment: Just noticed, it could be `DF1` and `DF_H` and/or `DF_D` that has an ID column.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! After specifying the columns I wanted, it worked!

Comment: Side note: `year(b.Status_Date)` returns an **INT** value - so why are you comparing to a string?? Also: T-SQL prefers `<>` for unequal (over `!=` - that's the C# style). So in the end, you should **drop** the unnecessary single quotes, and use : `year(b.Status_Date) <> 1900`

Comment: @marc_s: T-SQL simply allows both `<>` and `!=`; I really see no way to claim "the language" prefers one to the other. A better argument might be that ANSI SQL-92 only allows `<>`, so getting used to that helps when you're writing SQL that works in mulitple  engines. Having said that, a great many of those accept `!=` as well anyway (I don't know if perhaps `!=` was added in a late version) -- in fact with some testing on dbfiddle I couldn't find even a single engine that rejected `!=`, so make of that what you will. And of course `!=` as inequality existed *long* before C#.